# Collecting Values from a String between two different characters including the last value

Tags: python, regex

Example string:

```
x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=531, height_mm=299, name='\\\\\\\\.\\\\DISPLAY4', is_primary=True
```

I want to get every value behind the "=" sign.

With

```
print(re.findall(r"=(.*?),", "x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=531, height_mm=299, name='\\\\\\\\.\\\\DISPLAY4', is_primary=True"))
```

I get:

```
['0', '0', '1920', '1080', '531', '299', "'\\\\\\\\.\\\\DISPLAY4'"]
```

But I want the "True" from "is_primary" too

With

```
=(.*?)(,|$)
```

I can split the string in two groups and fetch the values from group1 with a for loop but
i think, there is a more beautiful way and i really want to see it

And is it maybe even possible to get the

```
"DISPLAY4"
```

out of:

```
"'\\\\\\\\.\\\\DISPLAY4'"
```

in the same expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use re.findall and then exclude matching `,` or `=` before and after the `=` sign, using a single capture group.

If the values themselves can not contain `'`  you could use also exclude matching it:

```
[^=\s,]+=[\\.']*([^=\s,']+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceK9xS/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"[^=\s,]+=[\\.']*([^=\s,']+)"
s = "x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=531, height_mm=299, name='\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.\\\\\\\\DISPLAY4', is_primary=True"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

A bit more precise match with 2 capture groups:

```
[^=\s,]+=(?:'(?:\\+\.\\+)?([^\s,=']+)'|([^\s,=]+))
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^=\s,]+=` Match 1+ chars other than a whitspace char `,` `=` and then match `=`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `'` Match the `'`
  - `(?:\\+\.\\+)?` Optionally match 1+ times `/`, a dot `.` and again 1+ times `/`
  - `([^\s,=']+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than a whitspace char `,` `=` `'`
  - `'` Match the `'`
  - `|` Or
  - `([^\s,=]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char `,` `=`
- `)` Close the non capture group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CIl2op/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/geJ2PI).

```
import re

pattern = r"[^=\s,]+=(?:'(?:\\+\.\\+)?([^\s,=']+)'|([^\s,=]+))"

s = "x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=531, height_mm=299, name='\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.\\\\\\\\DISPLAY4', is_primary=True"

res = [m.group(1) if m.group(1) else m.group(2) for _, m in enumerate(re.finditer(pattern, s), start=1)]
print(res)
```

Both will output:

```
['0', '0', '1920', '1080', '531', '299', 'DISPLAY4', 'True']
```